# How to import huge CSV file with 1000+ columns and millions of rows into MySQL Workbench (FAST)?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I start learning SQL recently, and I am having difficulty when importing CSV file into MySQL. I have a csv file that contains 1000+ columns and millions of rows, and I would like to import it into MySQL Workbench. Since there are 1000+ columns, I don't think the CREATE TABLE command would be the most efficient way of importing data as I will have to set the data type manually (for 1000 times).

I've tried the Table Import Data Wizard in MySQL Workbench. Although I've successfully imported the CSV file, however it took around 2 hours to complete the entire process.

I was wondering if there is any quicker and more efficient way of doing it? Any suggestions are appreciated :)

Comment: You probably cannot create a table with 1000+ columns. I recommend you need to think more about data modeling so you don't need to create a table that wide.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really get it. Do you mean I need to break down the columns into multiple tables? I've seen on YouTube that people imported the same CSV file into MS SQL server, and the processing time is way more shorter than mine. Does that have to do with the type of RDMS used? I was wondering if there is any way to shorten the processing time when importing CSV file into MySQL Workbench in my case?

Comment: In most forum, people suggested to use  LOAD DATA  to deal with huge CSV file with millions of rows, but the problem with this approach is that a table has to be created before performing LOAD DATA. There is no way for me to type and set up the 1000+ columns data types one-by-one manually.

Comment: Yeah, it's a pity there's no way to give a computer instructions to output some string (like a column definition) repeatedly, in some sort of looping structure.

Comment: MySQL has a hard limit of 1017 columns.  And, depending on the datatypes for the columns, the limit may be lower.